# Google Maps radius around point

Tags: sql, algorithm, google-maps

I have a question regarding a specific algorithm, can you guys please help me understand the following code, I want to implementing it, however I want to understand the code before implementation, I hope you guys understand what I mean.

```
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(-11232) ) * cos( radians( 21223 ) ) * cos( radians( 21223 ) - radians(23321) ) + sin( radians(-22321) ) * sin( radians( 23321) ) ) )
```

I understand it is looking for the radius, but how does it work? Good detail would be appreciated possible to a little maths formula.

Thanks in advance people.

Comment: Do you really mean those numbers? The 21223 etc are angles.

Comment: No I mean the whole algorithm ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(-11232) ) * cos( radians( 21223 ) ) * cos( radians( 21223 ) - radians(23321) ) + sin( radians(-22321) ) * sin( radians( 23321) ) ) )

Answer (score 1):

This formula is for calculating the distance between two points on a sphere.

You can read an explanation here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance.

11232 and 21223 are the coordinates on the sphere (although they look a bit strange to me), 3959 is the radius of the sphere.

Comment: Thanks, however can you please give me more information or any other link to give me more information regarding the formula. cheers

Comment: I think the documentation on Wikipedia should be sufficient.  If you need more mathematical explanations about it, you might post that question on math.stackexchange.com.